# SendGrid setup trouble

Tags: php, zend-framework, sendgrid

I just got my SendGrid account provisioned and the zip file uploaded to my server and now I'm trying to integrate it with my Zend Framework project. I tried to integrate slowly so I would only get a few errors at a time, starting off with just creating an email before trying to send it. This is all I have so far:

```
require_once(BASE_PATH . "/library/sendgrid-php/SendGrid.php");
require_once(BASE_PATH . "/library/sendgrid-php/SendGrid_loader.php");
$sendgrid = new SendGrid($username, $password);
        $mail = new SendGrid/Mail();
        $mail->addTo($email)
             ->setSubject('Subject')
             ->setText('');
        //$sendgrid->smtp->send($mail);
```

By the way, the first require is in there because SendGrid loader threw an error because it couldn't find SendGrid.php. Anyway, just these few lines of code produce all of these errors:

```
Warning: Missing argument 1 for SendGrid::__construct(), called in 
...InviteController.php on line 51 and defined in 
...library/sendgrid-php/SendGrid.php on line 13

Warning: Missing argument 2 for SendGrid::__construct(), called in 
...InviteController.php on line 51 and defined in 
...library/sendgrid-php/SendGrid.php on line 13

Warning: mail() expects at least 3 parameters, 0 given in 
...InviteController.php on line 51

Warning: Division by zero in ...InviteController.php on line 51

Fatal error: Call to a member function addTo() on a non-object in 
...InviteController.php on line 52
```

SendGrid's own guide, http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/get-started/integrate/examples/php-email-example-using-smtp/, basically just says upload the files to your server and include the loader and you're ready to go. I absolutely do not understand why I would be getting all of these errors. Did I miss a step in setting it up or something?

Comment: `new SendGrid/Mail();` should be `new SendGrid\Mail();`, not sure if that was just a typo in your question

Comment: With the backslash I get an unexpected input and parse errors. That did clear up the rest of them, but probably because it's just not making it past the parse error to actually execute.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? The \ is a namespace separator which means SendGrid requires 5.3.

Comment: 5.2.17 apparently. I'll bet that's the entire problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was just an outdated version of PHP. Sendgrid requires at least 5.3 for its namespace feature (the slash in the class name), to work correctly. My code couldn't evaluate the namespace and so it couldn't find the class it needed.